# How can use horizontal scrollbar of gridview in android?

Tags: android, gridview, scrollbar

```
<GridView
android:id="@+id/gridView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="100dip"
android:numColumns="8"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
android:stretchMode="none" >
</GridView>
```

i want to use both vertical and horizontal scrollbar in gridview as seen above.
i saw the vertical one does work well, but the horizontal one does not.
so i tried to fix it by placing the gridview under the Horizontal Scroll View as like below

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="100dip"
            android:numColumns="8"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
            android:stretchMode="none" >
        </GridView>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

even worse, it displays just one column of gridview and of course, there is no horizontal scrollbar.

How can i fix it?

Comment: As far as I know `GridView` is fixed to the screen width and so it's not possible to scroll in a horizontal direction. Putting a `GridView` inside a `HorizontalScrollView` doesn't solve the problem as it effectively gives an infinite space to surround the `GridView` and doesn't have scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` extends `AbsListView` class. In essence grid view is an listview with support for columns in addition to rows. So it doesn't support horizontal scrolling.

What you have done essentially by setting `android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"` attribute is to instruct the grid view to show both horizonatl and vertical scroll bars. Setting this attribute won't enable scrolling in a view (gridview and listviews have scrolling enabled intrinsically).

If you could explain a bit more on what you are trying to do, an alternative approach could be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

the Best Solution to used both horizonal and Vertically scroolview in android

```
      <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/seatLegendLayout">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_gridtableLayout"
                    android:layout_width="900dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <GridView
                        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:columnWidth="100dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:numColumns="9"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                        android:stretchMode="none"
                        android:verticalSpacing="1dp">

                    </GridView>


                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```